# mail.app rejecting correct password for gmail accounts

Tags: mail.app, gmail, password

Mail.app has stopped accessing several of my gmail accounts.  It gives the generic error "Mail can't connect to the account "xxxx".  Enter the password for user "myusernamehere".  When I enter the correct password, it circles back to this error. Going directly to gmail, I can login with that same password.

One of the two accounts with this problem is a new one I was setting up, but the other is my "main" account which has been in use with mail.app for years.

Answer (score 2):

The fix is to login to the google account affected, and then go to https://www.google.com/settings/security/lesssecureapps and select "Enable" for the question "Access for less secure apps."

Apparently this results from a change Google made several months ago to improve security, which is indeed becoming more and more important as Google accounts are tied to a wider and wider range of uses.  It is a mystery to me why it suddenly prevented my logging in now, but I wanted to share the solution I found in case anyone else encounters the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

I think relaxing security is the wrong answer to this problem, which I have just encountered myself.  Instead I downloaded EasyMail for Gmail, which supports the 2-step verification now required by Google. It seems fine, though I found the ads annoying so I upgraded for £3.89 to make it ad-free for life.

Comment: While this may be the issue they are having. I'd recommend using the default Gmail app for mail (or Inbox for Gmail) if they have two-factor authentication turned on. But this question didn't detail that they have it on.